# Windows window behaviour

Tags: windows-10

EDIT:
tl;dr; How to turn off Snap Assist (that is the word I was looking for)

Since Windows 10 there is this annoying behaviour from which I cant find the name off.

Previously, when I press the Windows-key + (left or right), one and only one window would move to the designated position.
When I do this now, all other windows that I have will move to the opposite site and I need to select one of them in order to continue.

I don't want to have this effect anymore, but I don't know how this procedure is called. Can anyone here help me?

Below you can see what I was trying to explain. Hope this helps

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is called snap assist. Here’s how to disable it.

https://www.howtogeek.com/365043/how-to-disable-snap-assist-in-windows-10/

Open your Windows settings and select the System category.

In the System Settings window, click the “Multitasking” tab over on the left. On the right, you’ll see several options in the “Snap” section. You can use those to turn off different aspects of the Snap feature, like whether dragging windows snaps them at all and whether snapped windows resize to fill available space.

If you only want to disable Snap Assist, turn off the “When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it” option.